# Can't install express and packages

Tags: node.js, express, npm

[image]

[image]

Hey, excuse me if this question is ridiculous but I can't handle with start in nodeJS, I try to install `npm install -g n` global and try install express locally but I cannot do this, I am trying install express like that `npm install express` before set my local path

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Can't you see the error messages?

Comment: The [package site for **n**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n) states that Windows is not supported, so you most likely won't be able to use it. The other installation only gave you warnings, so it should have been installed successfully

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are using the `Cmder` cmd prompt which is for Windows.  If you are on Windows, then the `n` node version control does not support it.  Here is their documentation that specifies that: https://github.com/tj/n

If you have NPM installed chances are **you already have Node.js** installed as well.  You can check by typing: `node -v`.

If you do not see a version # like `v7.0.0` after typing that, go to this page to download Node.js: https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Also, you will want to set up a **package.json file** by running **`npm init`** in your cmd prompt. Try running the same command you used to install `express` and then check the directory you installed it into, and you should see a **package.json** file.  Look in that package file and you will see **Express** listed as a dependency :)

Here are a few ways you can install packages.  Go to the base of your project directory where your package.json file is located and try:

- **npm i -S** `package name` (saves to your core dependencies)
- **npm i -D** `package name` (saves to your dev dependencies)
- **npm i -g** `package name` (saves globally)

**Core dependencies** are for packages that you want to use in production whereas **dev dependencies** are good for things like testing suites and build tools.  **Saving globally** is good when you want access the package's CLI from any directory in your command prompt.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: thank for help but look I set path C:\Users\Piotr\Desktop\API and next installed express and express is install in C:\Users\ not in path which I set

Comment: @V.R Did you try `npm init` before installing express?  It shows an error that you do not have a package.json file.